# Current index of the LI occurence

Tags: jquery, html-lists

The scenario is described below.

```
<li onmouseover="swapArrow_white()" onmouseout="swapArrow_black()"><a href="#">Menu<img src="common/images/downArrow.png" class="downarrow" /></a>
<li onmouseover="swapArrow_white()" onmouseout="swapArrow_black()"><a href="#">Menu<img src="common/images/downArrow.png" class="downarrow" /></a>
<li onmouseover="swapArrow_white()" onmouseout="swapArrow_black()"><a href="#">Menu<img src="common/images/downArrow.png" class="downarrow" /></a>
```

I need to change the Down arrow image on the mouseover event of the li. I am using the following script.

```
function swapArrow_white(){
            $("img.downarrow").attr("src","common/images/downArrowWhite.png");
        }

        function swapArrow_black(){
            $("img.downarrow").attr("src","common/images/downArrow.png");
        }
```

but, when ever mouseover event occurs, all the dropdown image get changed. It is not picking the current LI on which mouseover event occured.

is there any method to get the current LI so that only one image can change at one time

Please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try binding using the Each function to assign each image it's own hover action.

```
$('li a').each(function(){
    img = $(this).child('img');
    $(this).hover(function(){
        img.addClass('arrowDown');
    },function(){
        img.removeClass('arrowDown');
    });
});
```

Unless these arrows trigger JS events, CSS is still the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding events in jQuery so:

HTML:

```
<li class="changeColor"><a href="#">Menu<img src="common/images/downArrow.png" class="downarrow" /></a>
<li class="changeColor"><a href="#">Menu<img src="common/images/downArrow.png" class="downarrow" /></a>
<li class="changeColor"><a href="#">Menu<img src="common/images/downArrow.png" class="downarrow" /></a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('li.changeColor').mouseover(function(){$("img", this).attr("src","common/images/downArrowWhite.png");})
$('li.changeColor').mouseout(function(){$("img", this).attr("src","common/images/downArrow.png");})
```

Comment: thanks for the quick respones. But src is not the attribute of LI. we need to get the img element.

Comment: So just change $(this) to $("> img", this) or $("img", this)

Comment: @fantactuka Good idea. I made that change.

Comment: $("img", this) .. tried the same but did not get the required result.

Can you please help me with the code Fantactuka ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with Adam's solution but it would be better to use css for this:

```
.changeColor a {
  background: url('common/images/downArrow.png')
}

.changeColor a:hover {
  background: url('common/images/downArrowWhite.png')
}
```

I'm pretty sure that its possible to style `a` element to cover all area of the `li` (e.g. with display: block)

Js solution:

```
$('li.changeColor').hover(function() {
  $("img", this).attr("src","common/images/downArrowWhite.png");}
}, function() {
  $("img", this).attr("src","common/images/downArrow.png");}
})
```

Comment: there is already a background gradient image attached to the LI > a

so can not put the arrow image as background image.

Please suggest any other idea.

Comment: Add one more element like `span` and use 

.changeColor a span {
  background: url('common/images/downArrow.png')
}

.changeColor a:hover span {
  background: url('common/images/downArrowWhite.png')
}


This is much better then change src of image element

Comment: hard luck :)

still did not get the required result  mid night @ 2:00

Please put the code here ..anybody please help me .. i have my project release tomorrow..